# How to access a constant defined outside of smart contract

Tags: solidity

Let say if I have a contract defined like

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

uint256 constant MAX_TARGETS = 256;

contract Dummy {}
```

After the contract is deployed, is it possible to access the variable MAX_TARGETS using etherjs?

Answer (score 1):

> *After the contract is deployed, is it possible to access the variable MAX_TARGETS using etherjs?*

It is not.

When you compile the `Dummy` contract, the resulting bytecode consists of its content and all of its dependencies (parent contracts, libraries that are referenced from this contract, etc.). Since `MAX_TARGETS` is not a dependency of the `Dummy` contract, it's not even included in the bytecode.

You can validate it by inspecting the bytecode compiled from source with and without the `MAX_TARGETS` - in both cases the bytecode is the same.